# Installing an additional feature during product build for some Eclipse versions only

Tags: eclipse, tycho, p2

When building a product based on Eclipse 3.7+, I want to include a marketplace feature (org.eclipse.epp.mpc). I don't want to explicitly add this feature to one of the product features because I am also building for Eclipse 3.5. Is there a way to add this feature during the build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently not possible to create a product distribution which contains additional features, i.e. features which are not directly or indirectly referenced from the product. This enhancement was [requested in this ticket](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=361722), but is not available in the current Tycho version (0.16.0).

However there is the possibility to declare an optional greedy dependency to the marketplace feature from your product. Then, you could set up different target platforms in your build (through profiles) with (for 3.7) or without (for 3.5) the marketplace feature. With the optional greedy dependency, Tycho will then include the feature in the product installation in case it is available in the target platform.

Comment: I tried setting feature as optional, as well as adding to instructions to p2.inf - http://pastebin.com/NLFq0WtT, but get this error during build  - http://pastebin.com/uHqpANsM.

Comment: @AlexKravets: When using a feature for declaring the optional dependency, you should only reference the feature, not include it.