# Eclipse RCP: add optional dependencies

Tags: node.js, eclipse-plugin, dependencies, eclipse-rcp

I have [open source project  Nodeclipse on GitHub](https://github.com/PaulVI/nodeclipse-1/)
I want that during plugin installation, user can select optional features,
like Markdown support, JSHint and other plugins that have their own update site.

How to do that in Eclipse RCP plugins?

I guess I need to configure feature.xml in `org.nodeclipse.feature`

UPDATE:

Do I need to start using Tycho for that?

[image: Selection]

Example of Perforce installation

[image]

Comment: Similar question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591472/installing-an-additional-feature-during-product-build-for-some-eclipse-versions

Comment: That question is about Tycho, that we don't use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that is even possible.. You can however split your feature into more than one features. So the user can choose what to install.